# Is there a way to check the selected keyspace in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Is there a way to check the selected keyspace in Cassandra while using it through Java?

Context:
A subsystem uses authentication credentials to select a keyspace.  I'm working on a DTO that executes commands.  I have a hunch that i'm operating in the wrong keyspace (commands execute successfully in DevCenter but not within the Java code).

I'm new to Cassandra and this Java application so I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question more with sample code of how you are connecting to keyspace.

Comment: All set.  I found the configuration that dictated the keyspace.  I'm still unsure where the connection was being created.  I was hoping there was a simple call to print out the environment (keyspace, clusters, etc).